# Which facebook access token to choose?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Which [access token type](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) should I use to make a light and secure Open Graph call, say to get the number of likes on certain URL?

The first solution that came to me was to generate a user access token with just a "public profile" permission via Open Graph Explorer and use that one. But it didn't work, and it will expire, so I would have to re-generate the token every time.

The other one solution is to use an application access token which doesn't expire:

***app_id|app_secret***

It seems redundant to me, quote the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#apptokens):

> This can be used to modify the parameters of your app, create and
>   manage test users, or read your application's insights.

Why do I need to get so many privleges, if I just want to read some public data? And I don't want to expose my application to some possible malware intrusion in the case of a app_id and/or app_secret leak

The question is not only about how I can get the likes of certain URL, I guess it's more about how to use and manage access tokens wisely.

Comment: Next time you ask, try using better spelling and grammar. (at least capitalize your "i"'s)

Comment: I will. Sorry, English is just not my native language

Comment: What do you mean by "app_id|app_secret"?

Comment: I edited your comment to make the opening sentence a lot clearer. Read my edits if you want some grammar suggestions.

Comment: _“Why do I need to get so many privleges”_ – you don’t “need to get” those priviliges, with an app access token you already _have_ them. _“And I don't want to expose my application to some possible malware intrusion in the case of a app_id and/or app_secret leak”_ – well then make sure it _doesn’t_ leak.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant -  I have to approve all of those permissions  just to make a very light and secure Graph Call. Is there any better way to grant certain app permissions and get correlated set of functionality I want to exploit. It turns out like with the same permissions i can make a call to get some public data and at the same time can modify my app settings. It's smth that differs from how user access token works.

Answer (score 0):

All Facebook Graph API endpoints are [documented](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/). From this documentation, you will be able to learn which action on which endpoint requires which type of access token, and which permission scopes.

To get "the number of likes on certain URL" you cannot use graph API. Neither the [`/?id=URL` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/url), nor the `/OG-Object-ID` endpoint that you can derive from the former give you back a like count.

For websites that you manage, [Facebook Domain Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/platforminsights/domains) might give you what you are looking for.